# Radius at a height of a cylinder whose radius of the base and top may be different.

Tags: geometry

I have a cylinder whose radius of the base and top may be different.
I know the radius of the base and the top and i know the height of the cylinder.
I need to know the radius of the cylinder at a given height.

Comment: Does the radius increase linearly with the height?

Comment: Let $R$ and $r$ be the two radii, with the bottom one being $R$. Let $h$ be the full height, and $x$ the height we are interested in. We interpolate linearly. The radius at height $x$ is $R\frac{h-x}{h}+r\frac{x}{h}$.

Comment: "I have a cylinder whose radius of the base and top may be different." That's like saying "I have a square whose sides are not all the same."

Comment: Yes the radius increases linearly, I'm trying to create a function to use with Computer Graphics which draws a cylinder with certain parameters which it might end up a cone or a truncated cone. It would be fun to create one which doesn't increase linearly but that's too much work for me now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that the radius increases linearly and we thus have a cone with a possible chopped of top. In that case, let the cylinder have height $h$, the bottom radius is $a$ and the top radius is $b$. For height $x$ with $0\le x\le h$ we then get that the radius at $x$ is equal to $\frac{x}{h}(b-a)+a$ (Think about it).

Comment: Thank you for your help, i'm going to try that :)

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you very much.